# Calling a free floating function within a class

Tags: c++

I have a method inside the Foo class that needs to call the free floating function freeFloat. However, calling it results in a out of scope error.

```
Foo.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool Foo::method()’:
Foo.cpp:351:24: error: ‘freeFloat’ was not declared in this scope
     freeFloat();
```

The structure of the code looks something like this:

```
class Foo {
 public:
     virtual void method() {
         freeFloat();
     }

};

int main(){ 

}

bool freeFloat(){


}
```

Can this be done? If so, is it considered poor practice or in most cases OK? Is there a better placement for each method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function shall be declared before the class definition if it refers to the function.
Any name in C++ shall be declared before its using.

Comment: Phew! That was easy. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the function before calling it....

```
bool freeFloat();

class Foo {
 public:
     virtual void method() {
         freeFloat();
     }

};

int main(){ 

}

bool freeFloat(){


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `freeFloat` before you can call it. Either move the function definition to the top or add:

```
bool freeFloat();
```

to the top.