# Why can't I call any other overloads of the same function while inside a particular function overload in C++?

Tags: c++, function, compilation, overloading

It's best to illustrate this question with a simple program.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void printPoint(std::pair <int, int> point) {
    printPoint(point.first, point.second);
}

void printPoint(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
    std::pair <int, int> point(2, 3);
    printPoint(point);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like for the two `printPoint` functions to accomplish the same thing by taking advantage of overloads. However, while inside the scope of a particular overload of the `printPoint` function (in this case, the single-argument one), the compiler only lets me use that particular overload, so the code does not compile.

Why is this? Further, is there any way to mitigate this problem so that I don't have to re-write the same function body twice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a free floating function within a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059261/calling-a-free-floating-function-within-a-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaration order matters here.

Move the 2nd overload (`printPoint(int, int)`) before the 1st one (`printPoint(std::pair <int, int>`); otherwise it's invisible inside the 1st overload. i.e.

```
void printPoint(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
}

void printPoint(std::pair <int, int> point) {
    printPoint(point.first, point.second);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GvChW8Sz60y7XAtU)

Comment: Thank you. I was going nuts because I could've sworn this should compile. Turns out I keep forgetting declaration order matters in C++.

Comment: @jvn91173 Yes, declaration order does matter.

Comment: Does sometimes matter. The bodies (and ctor-init-lists) of member-functions are only evaluated after all members of the class are known though, as one exception.